# Set ESP8266 Soft-AP signal strength

Tags: esp8266, access-point, sming

I am using ESP8266 SMING framework.

I would like to adjust the signal strength of the soft-ap. Are there any APIs to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the Espressif sdk yields no such option for the AP mode. It seems like you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that you can do that with

```
WiFi.setOutputPower(20.5);  // set highest WiFi power
```

I'm using the Arduino API.
 
Using the (free) Android wifi analyzer app 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en_GB
I observed an increase in signal strength